# Adding javascript to capture Google Analytics Events in WordPress website

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, google-analytics

I want to add a javascript to capture the time spent on a page before exiting, and send those Events to Google Analytics (GA).

The reason I'm doing this is because it's likely that the landing page is also the exit page for this particular blog. And, as it turns out, GA doesn't accurately calculate the '[time spent on (exit) page](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/tick-tock-the-limitations-of-average-time-on-page-and-average-time-on-site-in-google-analytics-experiment/21439/)'.

So, I was informed of [this script](http://help.analyticsedge.com/googleanalytics/measuring-time-on-bounce-page/) which

> sets up a series of timers that trigger after a period of time, and when they do, they trigger a non-interaction event in Google Analytics.

I am using Universal Analytics, verified by the presence of the following code upon loading the page:

```html
 (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');
 
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X’, 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
```

And, I created a file called **bouncetime.js**, pasted in the above mentioned *Measuring Time On (Bounce) Page script*, and placed it inside the child theme's *js* directory.

I added the following code to my **functions.php** file:

```html
function ck_adding_scripts() {
wp_register_script('bouncetime', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/bouncetime.js', array('jquery'),'1', false);
wp_enqueue_script('bouncetime');
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ck_adding_scripts' );  
?>
```

But when I load the page in a browser I get the error:

> ReferenceError: Can't find variable: ga (anonymous
>   function)bouncetime.js:6

I'm a novice in javascript. It occurred to me that perhaps I need to add **analytics.js** as a dependency in the above mentioned **functions.php** code.  I've tried experimenting to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

No you dont need to add analytics.js, as the google analytics code itself will set that dependency and call the file for you.
I would advise you to skip placing your code in functions.php rather just place it in the header file directly

Comment: Thanks yisael.  'They' say that you shouldn't put code in the header file because it will be overwritten with updates.  But, I may well take your advice if it will get it working!

Comment: This is true. Another option is to use a js plugin which allows you to add any js code to the site. Further you should look into using Google tag manager as you won't need to put any of the code on the site as you can fire of all the events you want using their built in features

Comment: Thanks yisrael.  I went with the Javascript plugin, 'CSS & Javascript Toolbox' and it seems to be working well, no errors.  I did the free Google Analytics Academy Tag Manager Course, will need to do it again because i was overwhelmed at the time...  Really appreciate your help, it's taken days to get this working!